# NPM run build has return code not 0, hence my tests are not run - error procKil is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, npm

npm run build or npm run verify has error code not 1, hence my test code is not run.

I need my node version to be 14 and typescript version to be 3.9.7 intentionally.

When I see the npm logs, I see this

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--verbose'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.19.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle api@2.2.4~prebuild: api@2.2.4
6 info lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: api@2.2.4
7 verbose lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: PATH: /Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/pavanrao/api/node_modules/.bin:/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/shims:/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/protobuf@3/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/protobuf@3/bin:/Users/pavanrao/.jenv/shims:/Users/pavanrao/.jenv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/protobuf@3/bin:/Users/pavanrao/.jenv/shims:/Users/pavanrao/.jenv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
9 verbose lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: CWD: /Users/pavanrao/api
10 silly lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: Args: [ '-c', 'rm -rf ./dist && tsc' ]
11 silly lifecycle api@2.2.4~build: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
12 verbose stack ReferenceError: procKil is not defined
12 verbose stack     at procError (/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:366:38)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:335:5)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
13 verbose cwd /Users/pavanrao/api
14 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
15 verbose argv "/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/bin/node" "/Users/pavanrao/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.19.3/bin/npm" "run" "build" "--verbose"
16 verbose node v14.19.3
17 verbose npm  v6.14.17
18 error procKil is not defined
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is how my package.json looks

```
{
    "name": "api",
    "version": "2.2.4",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon index.ts",
        "build": "rm -rf ./dist && tsc",
        "copy-files": "cp -R ./schema/ ./dist/",
        "process-release-strategy": "nodemon release_strategy_process.ts",
        "watch": "tsc -w",
        "test": "jest",
        "preverify": "npm run build && rm -rf ./reports",
        "verify": "jest -i --coverage",
        "proto:build": "cd proto; buf build; cd ..",
        "codegen:buf": "cd proto; buf generate; cd .."
    },
    "devDependecies": {
...

}

Anything that can be done better?

Running on Mac M1.
```

Comment: You may want to try reinstalling that version of npm, `procKil` should be `procKill`

Comment: @Matt just bumped the version of node, it stopped. May be a bug in the 14.19.3 version?

Also, it's `procKil`, I picked that from the log

Comment: I'd say it was a problem with that install of node/npm, `procKil` doesn't appear in a release of `npm-lifecycle`, it's always `procKill`. Might something like a control-c during an install, or bad tar extract etc.

Comment: Didn't do tar extract, installed it through asdf. As you said, could be a thing I messed up during the install.

Answer (score 0):

Bumped the version of node from 14.19.3 to 14.20.0, it stopped occurring.